# Plot dataframe column by each entry belonging to certain range of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'total':[100,340,238,394,5859,324,5545,75858,563,613,123,6654,253,7567]}) 

#actual number of entries can be in thousands
```

And I want to first convert them in to ranges whatever they might be, for example range of 10 values. All values would be put into their respective bins. For example

```
[100-200]:[100, 123]
[200-300]:[238]
```

And then i want to plot a histogram to see which range is highest, which is second and so on.

I tried so far manually creating the ranges and sorting. But the whole point of analysis is to find the ranges that come out of the data instead of giving it myself. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'total': [100, 340, 238, 394, 5859, 324, 5545, 75858, 563, 613, 123, 6654, 253, 7567]})
m = x['total'].max()

jumps = []
# creating the jumps (ranges of 100)
for item in range(0, m, 100):
    jumps.append([item, item + 100])

# creating filter for each range
for item in jumps:
    filter_numbers = ((x['total'] >= item[0]) & (x['total'] < item[1]))
    print(x.loc[filter_numbers]) # you can save the data here and plot it later on
```

Here you go, note the last line of the code is what the data you looked for.

Now all you have to do is to save it in a pd and plot it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

To convert into ranges:

```
ranges = {}
for i in range(0, int(x.max()), 1000):
    start = i
    end = i + 1000
    r = '['+str(start)+'-'+str(end)+']'
    for value in x.values:
        if i<=value[0]<end:
            if r in ranges:
                ranges[r].append(int(value[0]))
            else:
                ranges[r] = [int(value[0])]
```

Data in ranges are in the format you wanted. Now you can use this data to plot in the way you want.